# using GoogleEarth plugin from VB.NET through FC.GEPluginCtrls

Tags: vb.net, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm really looking for a simple way to build VB.NET apps that use the GEplugin. So I have found this project that seems to do the dirty job I need: http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/

Well, all the code posted there around works on C#, but I need to have it on VB.NET. So I have tried this:

1. created a new 32-bit solution from VB.NET 2010 Express (I simply added

   ```
       <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget >
   ```

   inside the .vbproj file)
2. added a reference to FC.GEPluginCtrls.dll
3. inserted a GeWebBrowser control on the form
4. at the top of the code, added

   ```
       Imports FC.GEPluginCtrls
   ```

   then, in the form Load event, put this code:

   ```
       InitializeComponent()

       GeWebBrowser1.LoadEmbeddedPlugin()

       Do
       Loop Until GeWebBrowser1.PluginIsReady = False

       GeWebBrowser1.CreateInstance(ImageryBase.Earth)
   ```

   that, I think, would be equivalent to 
   http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/CreateInstance

So, the project compiles and doesn't get errors, but the GeWebBrowser control remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote the library you are using. You are not listening for the PluginReady event. http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/PluginReady

To use it with VB simply convert the basic examples to VB -
http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/ExampleForm

Also, a loop polling PluginIsReady is totally unnecessary as the PluginReady event is asynchronous.

To show the earth all you would need is the following.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GeWebBrowser1.LoadEmbeddedPlugin()
End Sub
```

To use the plugin when it has initialzesd use the PluginReady event. Something like.

```
Option Strict Off 
Public Class Form1
    Private Dim _ge as Object = Nothing
Private Sub GeWebBrowser1_PluginReady( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As FC.GEPluginCtrls.GEEventArgs) Handles GeWebBrowser1.PluginReady
        _ge = e.ApiObject ' reference to the Google Earth Plugin object
        MessageBox.Show(_ge.getApiVersion()) ' _ge is the plugin -use it just as in the javascript api...
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load( ByVal sender As System.Object,  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GeWebBrowser1.LoadEmbeddedPlugin() ' load the plugin
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your code is the same than mine, at least about the initialization of the component. However, on my system the plugin area remains blank and empty, without the Earth globe inside. It is not question to listen to the PluginReady event... because the plugin become ready but nothing appears on the screen. Anyway I have found a tricky solution embedding the plugin inside a HTML page, and sending commands on it using the InvokeScript method. It is better than nothing....

Comment: "It is not question to listen to the PluginReady event.." err yes it is - I wrote the library you are using. The library uses an embedded a HTML page and InvokeScript in the first place...